# Failed to connect service in another container by hostname with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  translate:
    restart: always
    # Docker file here: https://github.com/mashirozx/google-translate-server/blob/master/Dockerfile
    image: mashirozx/google-translate-server:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:30031:30031"
    command: "npm start -- --domain ${DOMAIN:-cn}"
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network

  app:
    image: app:dev
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
    depends_on:
      - translate
    links:
      - "translate:translationserver"
```

In `app` container, both hostname `translate` and `translationserver` is unable to resolve, and I tried to use the server public IP, http://public.IP:30031 is accessible in `app`. SO the problem is the hostname not resolved in `app` container.

Same question, but no one solve my problem:

[docker-compose fails to resolve service hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114703/docker-compose-fails-to-resolve-service-hostname)

[How do I set hostname in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924843/how-do-i-set-hostname-in-docker-compose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`links` is deprecated, since you don't need it to access other contianers in the same docker-network.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Try removing `links` and use in your `app` name `translate`: docker will resolve internal IP (docker vlan) to access it.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  translate:
    restart: always
    # Docker file here: https://github.com/mashirozx/google-translate-server/blob/master/Dockerfile
    image: mashirozx/google-translate-server:latest
    container_name: translate
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:30031:30031"
    command: "npm start -- --domain ${DOMAIN:-cn}"
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network

  app:
    image: app:dev
    container_name: myapp
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
    depends_on:
      - translate
```